# Netbeans Wizard, method storeSettings run twice

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I develop plugin for Netbeans IDE and I use Wizard with 1 step. (Just finish button on the first panel no other panels).

When I run I saw that the method `storeSetting` is called twice. How do I prevent running this method two times?

Answer (score 1):

Solwed, here is code which will execute just one time:

```
@Override
public void storeSettings(WizardDescriptor wiz) {

    if (wiz.getProperty("isSaved") == null) {
        // here operations to store data from wizzard


        // now we set property to inform WizardDescriptor is finish 
        wiz.putProperty("isSaved", true);

    }

}
```